# How to describe pixel width of a VideoObject or MediaObject in Schema.org and JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Using Schema.org vocabulary in JSON-LD, when describing the `height` and `width` dimensions of a `VideoObject`, do I write:

```json
"width": "100"
```

or

```json
"width": "100px"
```

or

```json
"width": {
    "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
    "unitCode": "E37",
    "value": "100"
}
```

The last option seems excessive, the middle option seems wrong and the first option seems lacking.

#### Update

I've seen that `width` can take a [`Distance`](http://schema.org/Distance) value:

> Properties that take Distances as values are of the form '
>   '. E.g., '7 ft'.

So … does that mean the correct entry would be:

```json
"width": "100 px"
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`height`](http://schema.org/height) and [`width`](http://schema.org/width) properties expect either a [`Distance`](http://schema.org/Distance) or a [`QuantitativeValue`](http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue) value.

Both of your corresponding examples are correct:

- `Distance` value:

  ```json
  "width": "100 px"
  ```
- `QuantitativeValue` value (`E37` is the UN/CEFACT Common Code for "pixel"):

  ```json
  "width": {
      "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
      "unitCode": "E37",
      "value": "100"
  }
  ```

For a consumer that supports both ways, these should be equivalent.

Possible risk when using a `Distance` value: a consumer might expect the unit to be written in a different way than `px` (e.g., `px.`, `pixel` etc.). I guess there is no standard abbreviation (at least the [Wikipedia article *Pixel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel) doesn’t specify one). You don’t have this risk with a `QuantitativeValue` value, because the units are standardized in the UN/CEFACT Common Code.

Comment: Wonderful, @unor. Thank you for the clarification. It's (still) rather hard to find explicit confirmation of this sort of thing across the web. I think I will risk `"width": "100 px"` for now, based on my guess that the abbreviation for pixels used in CSS (`px`) will eventually be the one officially adopted in Schema.org. (I can always do a multiple-file search and replace, if that turns out later not to be the case).